# Anet A8 extruder motor moves back and forth

Tags: extruder, stepper, anet-a8

[image]

This is what is happening to my motor. Any suggestions would help. 
1. I have tried adjusting the trimpot. 
2. Rewire the connector to match the one on the motherboard.
3. Anything else I found on the internet.

Comment: Does it continue if you ask an extruder move from the control panel? I think I remember this behavior from my electronic courses where a stepper motor was halfway from a step and sending a move command did fix the issue. (no guarantee, my memory could be faulty)

Comment: Low-hanging debug options: 1) connect the stepper to the driver of another axis 2) swap cable with another stepper/driver combo.  The behaviour will allow you to understand what part (cable/driver/stepper) is at fault.

Comment: What Mick said was exactly the issue. Went to check the continuity between all of the wires and found out that the black wire didn't have any. So I took the black wire out of the connector to take a look at it and the wire just feel out. It wasn't even crimped. Once I recrimped the wire and tested the connection. It works beautifully. Can't wait to start printing. Thanks Mick!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the continuity of the wires on the cable. Sometimes, they are not crimped correctly. Another common fault is crossed wires. In either case, the easiest diagnostic test is to substitute another cable, but please note the color coding of this replacement wire to match the cable you replace.

Answer (score 3):

The Anet A8 stepper motor 4 lead cable need to be correct in colour arrangement:

- mother board end: black-green-blue-red and extrauder
- stepper motor end: black-red-green-blue.

I bought DIY RepRap Anet A8 3d printer which came with one of the red lead end not attached, so in order to complete the build I used another lead from the Kossel delta 3D printer which has a different colour arrangement from the Anet A8 and made the motor rock back and forth as in your video.

It seems each colour lead carries a specific current and there are many different 4 colour cables out there.

Comment: I didn't realise that the order of the wires can be different.